# Converting errors to exceptions in PHP - script executions

Tags: php, oop

I've heard it's a good practice to convert all errors to exceptions. I totally agree with that, one of many pros of this solution is that I have only one handler instead of having two separate - for errors and for exceptions.

However, converting a notice/warning into the exception stops the script execution when one occurs. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: Uhm, yes? That's what uncaught exceptions do...

Comment: How can I catch unexpected notices/warnings? I don't. Should I catch everything that might throw a notice/warning?

Comment: You can use a catch (Exception $e) block. You can place these catches very high up in your code, to maximize what they catch; if you have a single entry point for your project, you can have your catch-all there.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful about using exceptions for error handling.  There are two schools of thought on this.

One school states that using exceptions for errors is a bad thing, and exceptions in general should be used sparingly, due to the flow of control confusion they can cause.

The other school likes them, because exceptions must be dealt with and they keep your code from being cluttered with if statements.

In any case, if you use exceptions, you have to decide on proper handling.  What happens when you catch them?  Can you recover?  How will you recover?  Will you terminate gracefully?

Simply using exceptions is not the end of the story, not by a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exceptions. Example function:

```
function myFunction($num){
    if(!is_int($num)){
        throw new Exception('Int expected. ' . gettype($num) . ' given instead.');
    }
}
```

Then catch any exceptions that may or may not be thrown (**IF** it makes sense to catch them):

```
try{
    myFunction('Hello?');
}
catch(Exception $e){
    //Do something
    var_dump($e);
}
```

You should also look into the function [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php):

> Sets the default exception handler if an exception is not caught
>   within a try/catch block. Execution will stop after the
>   exception_handler is called.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. Let's say I'll use try-catch on the whole website. It will catch notices/warnings properly, but errors won't stop script execution. Not-catching exceptions will execute scripts on fatal errors, but also on notices/warnings. Not to mention that in the first case I won't have an access to the handler.